# Paypal pro do I still need to use ipn?

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-ipn

When using paypal pro (never leaves site to process payment) do I still need to use ipn or is the api response enough?

If not how can I set the notify_url in a paypal api DoDirectPayment.

Sorry if I haven't explained this very well

Comment: It isn't necessary to use IPN if you use the API. By executing PayPal's DoDirectPayment method, you will receive a response back regarding the transaction without leaving your site. You can persist these details to your "notify_url" or execute the method in your "notify_url" and handle your transaction processing there.

Answer (score 1):

The API response should suffice. From the API response you can already tell if the payment has been accepted or not.